# Global incremen in thread PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I am running 4 threads running in same time. (Threads are running `work()` function in same time in this case)

```
global $i;
$i = 1;

function work($address) {
    while($i < 1000) {
        $i++;
        ----
        if($i == something) some job... 
        ----
    }
}
```

For some reason this don't do the job. 
Threads do sometimes same circle in while, so I have later some duplicate values. (probably they have some critical section) 
Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Not sure I understand but the `global i$;` needs to be in the function.

Comment: @AbraCadaver then all threads will have their own $i variables. I want for example first thread to do $i = 1, then increment value, when next thread do that part of code to have $i = 2...

Comment: Yes, your code is causing all threads to have their own $i.  If you move global then its global in all functions.  Or just use `$GLOBALS['i']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The counter object must be thread safe, it must also employ synchronized methods.

Follows is an example of such code:

```
<?php
class Counter extends Threaded {

    public function __construct($value = 0) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /** protected methods are synchronized in pthreads **/
    protected function increment() { return ++$this->value; }
    protected function decrement() { return --$this->value; }

    protected $value;
}

class My extends Thread {

    /** all threads share the same counter dependency */
    public function __construct(Counter $counter) {
        $this->counter = $counter;
    }

    /** work will execute from job 1 to 1000, and no more, across all threads **/        
    public function run() {
        while (($job = $this->counter->increment()) <= 1000) {
            printf("Thread %lu doing job %d\n", 
                Thread::getCurrentThreadId(), $job);
        }
    }

    protected $counter;
}

$counter = new Counter();
$threads = [];

while (($tid = count($threads)) < 4) {
    $threads[$tid] = new My($counter);
    $threads[$tid]->start();
}

foreach ($threads as $thread)
    $thread->join();
?>
```

work() seems superfluous, this logic should be in the ::run function most likely.